# Importing data into two postgres servers works on one, not on other

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, psql

I dumped my production db from an Amazon RDS postgresql instance and on occasion, I restore production to our staging and development databases. 
 Currently the staging and development databases reside on an RDS instance and the import works great. I am currently attempting to restore the database to a postgres installation that isn't an RDS instance and I continuously get the error `invalid command \N` before that I get `ERROR:  relation "locations" does not exist`. I have been trying everything to get this to work. I have recreated the database several times ensuring all of the settings match what I can see of the RDS instance, and am having no luck.

I am attempting to use `psql -h {host} -U {user} -d {db} < production.sql`

Comment: maybe related : https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/259007/how-do-i-dump-a-postgres-table-and-restore-under-another-user-role